# How to round UIBezierPath line edge?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

I have a line drawn by `UIBezierPath`:

```
let line = CAShapeLayer()
line.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                          radius: radius,
                          startAngle: CGFloat(114.0/180.0) * .pi,
                          endAngle: .pi,
                          clockwise: true).cgPath
line.lineWidth = LINE_WIDTH
line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor
line.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

I try to round the corner by adding some new `CAShapeLayer()`:

```
let corner = CAShapeLayer()
corner.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: coordByCorner(114.0*1.00035),
                           radius: LINE_WIDTH/2,
                           startAngle: CGFloat(114.0/180.0) * .pi,
                           endAngle: CGFloat(114.0/180.0 + 1) * .pi,
                           clockwise: false).cgPath
corner.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
corner.fillColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor

line.addSublayer(corner)
```

But I think this is a bad variant and when I change colors for layers, colors changes with different timeInterval.

Also, this all looks like this:

[image]

P.S.: 1.00035 there is to remove the gap between layers. And alpha needs to be < 1.0 (0.1 - 0.9). So how to do this while keeping the alpha?

Comment: After edits, your question completely differs from original one, which leads to all previous answer invalidation. Remember that answers are also (and mainly) added with a view to benefit future visitors with similar problems. The original problem was solved, that should be a different question, consider posting it separately.

Comment: Fayer, the original problem was solved but that was a "crutch". After I try to change answer code and added question info. The question always remained the same, so I don't see a problem in changing right answer, because my problem not solves for all time I changing question info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem solved by adding kCALineCapRound

```
let line = CAShapeLayer()
line.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                      radius: radius,
                      startAngle: CGFloat(114.0/180.0) * .pi,
                      endAngle: .pi,
                      clockwise: true).cgPath
line.lineWidth = LINE_WIDTH
line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.9).cgColor
line.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
line.lineCap = kCALineCapRound // this parameter solve my problem
```

Comment: `.round` on Swift 5

Comment: What if I want cornerRadius 8?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this is to create path shifted inwards by the desired `cornerRadius`, stroke it with the twice as thick line and apply rounded line joining style.

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()

layer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
layer.fillColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
layer.lineWidth = 2.0 * cornerRadius
layer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
layer.path = getSemicirclePath(
    arcCenter: arcCenter,
    radius: radius,
    cornerRadius: cornerRadius
)

func getSemicirclePath(arcCenter: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> CGPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath(
        arcCenter: CGPoint(x: arcCenter.x, y: arcCenter.y - cornerRadius),
        radius: radius - cornerRadius,
        startAngle: .pi,
        endAngle: 2.0 * .pi,
        clockwise: true
    )
    path.close()
    return path.cgPath
}
```

Here is the example result:

[image]

Comment: How to do this element opaque? ( need to use UIColor with alpha <1.0)

Answer (score -1):

Another way as per current version

```
line.path.lineCapStyle = .round
```

Comment: You mean `line.lineCap = .round` or `line.lineJoin = .round`.

Comment: mistyping.
I mean
`line.path.lineCapStyle = .round`

Comment: But `CGPath` doesn't have a `lineCapStyle` property. `line` is `CAShapeLayer`. `line.path` is `CGPath?`.

Comment: You should edit your answer to make it correct.